# manipulateWidget with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create interactive `ggplot2`s. `manipulateWidget` doesn't seem to cut it (example below), or does it?

```
library(manipulateWidget)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

mydata <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = rnorm(100))

myPlot <- function(type, lwd) {
  if (type == "points") {
    plot_ly(mydata, x= ~x, y = ~y, type = "scatter", mode = "markers")
  } else {
    plot_ly(mydata, x= ~x, y = ~y, type = "scatter", mode = "lines", 
            line = list(width = lwd))
  }
}

myPlot("points")

manipulateWidget(
  myPlot(type, lwd),
  type = mwSelect(c("points", "lines"), "points"),
  lwd = mwSlider(1, 10, 1, .display = type == "lines")
)

myggplot <- function(type, lwd) {
  if (type == "points") {
    ggplot(mydata, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
  } else {
    ggplot(mydata, aes(x, y)) + geom_line(size = lwd)
  }
}

myggplot("points")

manipulateWidget(
  myggplot(type, lwd),
  type = mwSelect(c("points", "lines"), "points"),
  lwd = mwSlider(1, 10, 1, .display = type == "lines")
)
```

If that's true, what's are good alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ggplot` object is not a htmlwidget, so that does not work. You can convert it to a htmlwidget with the `ggiraph` package.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggiraph)
library(manipulateWidget)

myggplot <- function(type, lwd) {
  if (type == "points") {
    gg <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + 
      geom_point_interactive()
  } else {
    gg <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + 
      geom_line_interactive(size = lwd)
  }
  girafe(ggobj = gg)
}

manipulateWidget(
  myggplot(type, lwd),
  type = mwSelect(c("points", "lines"), "points"),
  lwd = mwSlider(1, 10, 1, .display = type == "lines")
)
```

[image]